# Why I cannot keep call api if fail?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Below if my code...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var counter=0;
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://www.test.com:1234/testService",
        method: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        data: data
    })
    .done(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    })
    .fail(function(errMsg) {
        console.log(errMsg);
        counter++;
        console.log(counter);
        if(counter <=3){
            $.ajax(this);
        }
        else {
            alert("Three times failed");
        }
    });
});
```

Run this code will get correct data from API.

However, if I remove the "e" in the end of api url, the API will failed and what I want is to retry again until failed three times and alert some message.

But this code is not working.

What should I do?

Comment: Learn more about functions: http://eloquentjavascript.net/03_functions.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you can do is create a function that makes the ajax request and on failure invoke the function again.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var counter = 0;

    function apiCall() {
        $.ajax({
                url: "http://www.asiavista.com.tw:9595/ccplapi/service.svc/CheckService",
                method: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                data: JSON.stringify({ClientType: 1})
            })
            .done(function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            })
            .fail(function (errMsg) {
                console.log(errMsg);
                counter++;
                console.log(counter);
                if (counter <= 3) {
                    apiCall(); // Try api call again
                } else {
                    alert("Three times failed");
                }
            });
    }

    apiCall(); // Trigger the first api call
});
```

Comment: `this` doesn't refer to `document`. It either refers to `window` or in this case I think it refers to the `jqXHR` object created by `$.ajax`. You are right that using `this` is incorrect, but it doesn't refer to what you claim.

Comment: you are right! it refers to the jqXHR object. Quickly checked the this in dev tool but checked it within the document ready callback only and not within the xhr callback. Thanks.